# FlaskForm modal submit custom validator not called

Tags: jquery, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using a FlaskForm within a modal. The modal is setup like this:

`<form id="form_id" action="action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

And within the footer:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" form="form_id">Save</button>
```

This means that it immediately validates and calls the 'action' url when a user taps on Save. This works fine and if one of the fields doesn't validate correctly it shows a nice popup above the field.

BUT, for one field I've been trying to set a custom validator:

```
validators=[InputRequired(), validate_function]
```

But my issue is that this function is not called when using the automatic submit-functionality! It seems that it only validates existing validators such as 'InputRequired()' but it ignores my custom validators.

I found out if I validate it myself, for example when the action method is called and I do this:

```
form = TestForm(obj=request.form)
form.validate():
```

Then my own custom validator function is perfectly called. But I would like it to be called also when simply tapping submit on the modal form.

I know that I can intercept the submit and call the validate myself in JQuery and then it will probably work but I think this should be able to work as well... Does anybody have the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I believe I now know why this simply can not work. It's because I actually never really used the WTForm validation. I used the automagical HTML5 form validation. This automatically validates fields where e.g. 'required' is added to the html. So I guess the form.validate() was never really called in my case.

So I guess the only solution (to also keep the modal open and not dismissed) is to intercept the submit and call validate within jquery myself. Hope this helps someone someday :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can't you maintain the modal window using e.preventDefault on jquery submit function and post the form to server and user form.validate_on_submit()? and if there is an error you return the error message into JSON and Ajax will get it as response and display it in modal window?

Comment: Or Another solution will be implement two separate form validation layer: 1) Flask-WTF for better security 2) Jquery form validation. 1) and 2) will be pretty much the same validation content but 2) will provide better interactiveness.

Comment: @Jessi suggestion is the only practical solution for a well designed web app. Client side Javascript validation for better UI, and server side validation for robust logic. WTforms provides server side (as does package webargs), and HTML5 can do some limited validation and otherwise you need to use JS, but there are often JS libraries which have this integrated, for example VeeValidate which integrates with Vue.js (if you know that JS framework)

Comment: @Jessi yeah that’s exactly what I ended up doing. I sent the form serialized using an ajax request and validated some stuff in python, then sent a json back with status error or not. If error it displayed an alert (and modal would stay) and if not it would submit it in jquery :) I knew I could do this already but I hoped it wasn’t necessary... but I guess it is.

Comment: @Jessi I wonder though what the jquery form.validate() does. Does it also only do the limited validation? Or should that actually automatically perform the custom validators from wtform as well? I think not since I don't see it getting called..

Comment: built in Jquery https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ allows you to either user HTML validation as Jquery validation or let you implement a custom validation. It does not interact with Flask WTF validation (it is separate). If using WTF is must and you want extra validation on Client side for better interactiveness (meaning as user types something wrong, without sending the request back to server, it displays the error instantly) I'd recommend using https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/    Doing it this way will prevent you from writing custom JS validation.